# docker, second mavlan created. However container do not bind ip address

Tags: docker

I am facing a problem with docker and macvlan.

I have a dedicated server.

There are 3 blocks of ip address:

First block, 2 ips
`51.xx.yy.65`
`51.xx.yy.66`

Second block, 4 ips
`167.xxx.yyy.168`
`167.xxx.yyy.169`
`167.xxx.yyy.170`
`167.xxx.yyy.171`

```
At this point, I create my first mavlan. Because I only had these two blocks...


    docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=51.xx.yy.65/24 --subnet=167.xxx.yyy.168/24 
    --gateway=51.xx.yy.254 --gateway=167.xxx.yyy.254 -o parent=eno1 pub_net2


    And then, I ran my docker containers...

    docker run -dit --restart=always --ip=51.xx.yy.66 --mac-address 02:00:xx:xx:9c:d3 
    --net=pub_net2 --name=mycontainer myimage 

    docker run -dit --restart=always --ip=167.xxx.yyy.168 --mac-address 00:xxx:xxx:0a:ad:3f 
    --net=pub_net2 --name=mycontainer myimage 

    At this point, everything is perfect and working fine.

    My containers can be accessed from outside, pinging ips, perfectly.


    And now, the issue begins...

    I received the Third ip block, 4 ips
        '192.zz.zzz.48' 
        '192.zz.zzz.49'
        '192.zz.zzz.50'
        '192.zz.zzz.51'

    Then, I create a new macvlan:

    docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.zz.zzz.48/20 --gateway=192.zz.zzz.254  -o 
    parent=eno1.20 pubmcvlan4

    Although the new network created, the following container cannot be accessed or ping the     
    ip from outside.

    docker run -dit --restart=always --ip=192.zz.zzz.51 --mac-address=02:zz:zz:5a:e5:85 --
    net=pubmcvlan4 --name=mycontainer myimage


    Am I missing something?


    Is it possible to edit a already created macvlan?  Because, I cannot delete one with 
    containers attached to it.


    Thank you for any help!

    
    Best regards,

    Humberto
```